# Setting Excel worksheet protection with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, worksheet

I'm trying to set worksheet permissions for an XLSM file using EPPlus but it seems I can only set the default protection level, individual protections are not being set. For the record, I'm trying to accomplish programmatically method 1 in [this article](http://blog.softartisans.com/2013/10/01/kb-sorting-locked-cells-in-protected-worksheets/). Here's the code I'm using:

```
using (var p = new ExcelPackage("output.xlsm"))
{
    var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];

    // Set some cell values here

    // Filtering, sorting, protection
    ws.Cells[7, 1, 10, 5].AutoFilter = true;
    ws.View.FreezePanes(7, 1);
    ws.ProtectedRanges.Add("FilteredCells", new ExcelAddress(7, 1, 10, 5));

    // Worksheet protection
    ws.Protection.AllowAutoFilter = true;
    ws.Protection.AllowDeleteColumns = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowDeleteRows = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowEditObject = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowEditScenarios = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowFormatCells = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowFormatColumns = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowFormatRows = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowInsertColumns = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowInsertHyperlinks = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowInsertRows = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowPivotTables = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = false;
    ws.Protection.AllowSelectUnlockedCells = true;
    ws.Protection.AllowSort = true;
    ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;
    ws.Protection.SetPassword("hunter2");

    p.SaveAs(new FileInfo("output.xlsm"));
}
```

This runs without errors, but when I open the file in Excel, or load it back into EPPlus, I find that different protection options have been applied:

```
AllowAutoFilter = false
AllowDeleteColumns = false
AllowDeleteRows = false
AllowEditObject = true
AllowEditScenarios = true
AllowFormatCells = false
AllowFormatColumns = false
AllowFormatRows = false
AllowInsertColumns = false
AllowInsertHyperlinks = false
AllowInsertRows = false
AllowPivotTables = false
AllowSelectLockedCells = true
AllowSelectUnlockedCells = true
AllowSort = false
IsProtected = true
```

These obviously aren't the permissions I set before, so how can I make sure they are set correctly? Everything else is saved correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the source:

https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelSheetProtection.cs

Setting the `IsProtected` property is overwriting your choices:

```
 public bool IsProtected
    {
        get
        {
            return GetXmlNodeBool(_isProtectedPath, false);
        }
        set
        {
            SetXmlNodeBool(_isProtectedPath, value, false);
            if (value)
            {
                AllowEditObject = true;
                AllowEditScenarios = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DeleteAllNode(_isProtectedPath); //delete the whole sheetprotection node
            }
        }
    }
```

Move your `IsProtected = true` call to the start of the code or handle however you want, but you are accidently overriding your previous choice. I would look at the properties at that link to see which ones are going to override your existing selections.