# Create Excel document with EPPlus and assign user with Information Rights Management

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

Is there a way, using EPPlus, to create an Excel document and protect it's content so that only specific user(s) can access the information inside it.  This is possible when manually creating an Excel document and using the IRM capabilities within Excel, but I've not yet found a way of doing this at the point the Excel document is created using EPPlus.

I have tried embedding a VBA sub routine using Workbook_Open(), but many companies set policies to prevent running Macros on Office documents when they open because of the threat of viruses/malware.

IRM primarily controls WHO can access the content of the document, which is different to the Worksheet Protection capabilities in EPPlus that restrict WHAT someone can do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Excel worksheet protection with EPPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897500/setting-excel-worksheet-protection-with-epplus)

Comment: IRM is very different to "worksheet protection".  It determines WHO is permitted to access the contents of the document.  Worksheet protection determines WHAT can be done with the document, though IRM also adds another layer to that.

Comment: @JonO, could you create / open / a Excel file with IRM ?

Comment: Yes, I can manually create an Excel file and then restrict access to it via IRM.  My question is to whether there is a way to automate that in EPPlus.